# How to stop text in table HTML

Tags: html, html-table

How to stop text from make the table width longer and
make a new line instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a table width:

```
<table width="50%">
  ...
</table>
```

Width is also applicable to `<td>`.

Other than that, you may also want to take a look at CSS.

Comment: You may want to specify a definite value to make the table width same when the browser window is resized.
Like: <table width="200px">

Comment: @Vinnie HTML is not CSS. The (deprecated) with attribute doesn't take a unit unless it is a percentage. It should be 200 not 200px (which is an error - although not one that can be picked up by a validator as the DTD expresses the width attribute as being CDATA - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html#Length )

Answer (score 0):

Use a 
    `<br>`
when you want to break the line...